# Is it appropriate to omit "will not be"?

Tags: modal-verbs, future, present-tense, ellipses, will-be-going

Often, someone will say:

> I'm not living in a senior's home!

When the intended meaning is:

> I will not be living in a senior's home!

Is this acceptable?

Comment: It is common to use the present tense instead of the future, though it can be ambiguous

Comment: @Henry and Mahnax: "I am (not) going" is present tense, too.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道: needs amplification.  "I am going to the pub" is present tense.  "I am going to be there all day" is future. (it's a cunning plan to confuse the foreigners)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two quotes don't actually have the same meaning.  "I'm not living there!" is close to "I refuse to live there", while "I'm not going to be living there" is a prediction.  Technically, the first is "I will not live there", while the second is "I shall not live there", but I doubt whether many people these days appreciate the difference, particularly with exclamation marks and apostrophes involved.

Comment: Edited, better?

Comment: Sometimes I wish people *did* use explanation marks. It would make life easier. =)